# Funny double infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was playing with a modified version of Pascal's triangle (with ${n \choose k}^{-1}$ instead of $n \choose k$ everywhere) and this infinite sum popped out:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-1)} $$

The partial sums seem to approach $\alpha \approx 1.317...$

Does a closed form for $\alpha$ exist?

Comment: Hm, I think a similar question was asked before.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is not difficult to de-nest such double series.

> **Lemma 1.** For any $k\geq 2$, we have
>   $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+k-1)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n)_k}=\frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot(k-1)!}.$$

**Proof:** it is enough to exploit [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and a geometric series, since:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n)_k}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+k)}&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n\geq 1}B(k,n)\\&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}(1-x)^{k-1}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-x)^{k-1}x^{n-1}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{k-2}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-2}\,dx = \frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot(k-1)!}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

In particular, we have:
$$ S = \sum_{k\geq 2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n)_k} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m\cdot m!}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{m!}\,dx = \color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx}.$$
The latter is not an elementary integral but an [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

At last, a huge **WELCOME to MSE**.

Answer (score 16):

Swapping the order of summation we see the reciprocals of [OEIS sequence A001563](http://oeis.org/A001563), i.e. $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2F(n*n!)) tells us the sum is $$Ei(1)-\gamma$$

Ei is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).  Of course, this is sort of circular, since $Ei(1)$ is basically the series we're trying to compute, up to a constant $\gamma$ difference.

This is probably as "closed form" as you're going to find.

Answer (score 15):

[Not an answer, but too long to fit as a comment.]

*[Edit: @adjan points out that this is known as the Leibniz harmonic triangle, which I was unaware of.]*

I don't know if this is related or not: I noticed a curious fact a few years ago about reciprocals of binomial coefficients. If you take Pascal's triangle, but instead of putting $\binom{n}{k}$ in each entry, you put the reciprocal of $\,(n+1)\binom{n}{k}, $ you get an upside-down Pascal's triangle, with each number being the sum of the two numbers *below* it:

\begin{array}
\\&&&&&1
\\&&&&\frac12&&\frac12
\\&&&\frac13&&\frac16&&\frac13
\\&&\frac14&&\frac1{12}&&\frac1{12}&&
\frac14
\\& \frac15&&\frac1{20}&&\frac1{30}&&\frac1{20}&&\frac15
\\\ .^{\large{.}^{\LARGE{.}}}&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&{}^{{}^{{}^{\LARGE{.}}}}{}^{\hspace{-1mu}\large{.}}.
\end{array}
$$ $$
The proof that it works is straightforward:
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\frac1{(n+1)\binom{n}{k}}+\frac1{(n+1)\binom{n}{k+1}}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k+1}}
\\&=\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{k!\,(n-k)!}{n!}\frac{(k+1)!\,(n-k-1)!}{n!}
\\&=\frac1{n+1}\frac{(n+1)!}{\bcancel{(k+1)!}\cancel{(n-k)!}}\frac{k!\,\cancel{(n-k)!}}{n!}\frac{\bcancel{(k+1)!}\,(n-k-1)!}{n!}
\\&=\frac{\cancel{(n+1)!}}{\cancel{(n+1)\cdot n!}}\frac{k!\,(n-k-1)!}{n!}
\\&=\frac1{n\binom{n-1}{k}}.
\end{align}

I have no idea if this is well-known or not — I hadn't come across it before.

Comment: It's well known, for centuries. One minute (!) of googling gave me this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_harmonic_triangle

Comment: The entries even have their own symbol, $\left[{n\atop k}\right]$

Comment: @adjan, not quite fond of that symbol being used for Leibniz; I prefer it being used for Stirling cycle numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @adjan -- it was simple enough that I figured it had to be known.  (It didn't show up in a search for me when I tried, but that was many years ago. I should have searched again before posting on MSE now.)

Comment: @adjan I've seen the notation $\left[{n\atop k}\right]$ used for unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind, which are different from this. Do you have a source for the usage of $\left[{n\atop k}\right]$ for these harmonic triangle numbers?

Comment: @MitchellSpector The German version of the linked Wikipedia article. Here's another source that uses it (it's in German as well) https://books.google.de/books?id=B-nOBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=harmonisches+dreieck&source=bl&ots=RAutjHcA7o&sig=okEskEPCE4n9atEPszpoGegs0Zw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyrefe0dXPAhVMbRQKHbWDCAU4ChDoAQhDMAk#v=onepage&q=harmonisches%20dreieck&f=false (page 47)

Comment: @adjan Interesting, thank you. It would appear it might be a German usage. (As I recall, the use for Stirling numbers was popularized relatively recently by Knuth.)