# Computing $\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

I have a series question which I can not solve for two days.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+p)} = \frac{1}{p\cdot p!}$$

How can I prove and solve this equation?

Comment: Write numerator as  $$\dfrac{n+p-(n+1)}{p-1}$$ and use Telescoping Series

Comment: Your formula would be correct if your denominator was $n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)$.

Comment: You may use creative telescoping or Euler's Beta function as shown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964430/funny-double-infinite-sum/1964478#1964478

Comment: This has been asked at least a couple of times before, I don't know the links off hand but it will likely be closed as duplicate when someone gets around to finding them (Jack's is close but asks for more).

Answer (score 6):

Note the following $$\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition the summation becomes $$\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^∞ \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}\right)$$
We can use the [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). The consecutive terms cancel. So your answer is incorrect. The correct answer would be $$\frac{1}{p-1} \times \frac{1}{(1+1)(1+2)....(1+p-1)}=\frac{1}{(p-1)p!}$$
We are done! As mentioned by @ThomasAndrews, the formula would be correct if the denominator was $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)$ which can be confirmed through the same method.

Comment: How did we find $$ \frac{1}{p-1}$$ in the second line?

Comment: @Onur $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}$ is $$\frac{1}{p-1} \times \frac{(n+p)-(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}$$Which becomes $$\frac{1}{p-1} \times \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)....(n+p-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)}$$

Comment: @Onur Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, now I certainly saw it. Thanks for the help. I would call the publisher to warn them about their mistake. :)

Comment: @Onur You get money if you do that in my country :) I hope you would accept my answer?

Comment: @ S.C.B Of course. Your answer was the exact one I was looking for. I hope they give money here as well, though I doubt it. :)

Comment: @ S.C.B I already upvoted. But it seems my reputation is not high enough for my vote to be recorded.

Comment: @Onur You need 15 reputation for that privillege, unfortuantely.

Comment: @Onur Though you can still accept (i.e., click on the check button button) at that level.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)} = \frac{n!}{(n+p)!}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma(n+p+1)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\beta(n+1,p)$$
then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)....(n+p)} 
&=& 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\beta(n+1,p)\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1t^{n}(1-t)^{p-1}dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n}(1-t)^{p-1}dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1\frac{t}{1-t}(1-t)^{p-1}dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1t(1-t)^{p-2}dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1t^{p-2}(1-t)dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1t^{p-2}-t^{p-1}dt\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\\
&=& 
\frac{1}{p!(p-1)}
\end{eqnarray}
For $p=2$ we know 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac12$$
that shows our answer is **true**.