# Sum of infinite series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i(i+1)(i+2)...(i+n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, factorial

Lets define the following series
$$S_n =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i(i+1)(i+2)...(i+n)}.$$
I know that $S_0$ does not converge so let's suppose $n \in N$ and define $S_n$ for some $n$. We have $S_1=1$ , $S_2=\frac1 4$ , $S_3=\frac 1 {18}$ , $S_4=\frac 1{96}$ , $S_5=\frac 1{600}$ etc..
the numerator in all results is 1
the pattern in denominator is $[1,4,1,96,600...]$ and  [can be found here](https://oeis.org/A001563) that is equal to $n*n!$
Finally I want to prove the general equality:
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i(i+1)(i+2)...(i+n)}=\frac 1 {n*n!}$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964430/funny-double-infinite-sum

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Telescopic sum and
$$\frac{n}{i(i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+n)}=\frac{1}{i(i+1)\cdots(i+n-1)}-\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+n)}.$$

Comment: I don't think there is n in the numerator

Comment: Of course, You made the point with separating the fraction for telescopic sum,that is what i have missed

Comment: @Manthanein n is a constant, the summation is over i, so...

Comment: @Landon Carter I totally agree with that but Please check my answer for what I meant to say

Answer (score 6):

If you failed to see the telescoping nature of the series, here is an alternative approach that makes use of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

\begin{align*}
S_n &= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{i (i + 1) (i + 2) \cdots (i + n)} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdots (i - 1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots (i - 1)i(i + 1) \cdots (i + n)}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{(i - 1)!}{(i + n)!}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (i)}{\Gamma (i + n + 1)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma (i) \Gamma (n + 1)}{\Gamma (i + n + 1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \text{B}(i, n + 1)\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \int_0^1 t^{i - 1} ( 1 - t)^n \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \int_0^1 (1 - t)^n \left [\sum_{i = 1}^\infty t^{i - 1} \right ] \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \int^1_0 (1 - t)^n \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \int^1_0 (1 - t)^{n - 1} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1)} \left [-\frac{1}{n} (1 - t)^n \right ]^1_0\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma (n + 1) n}\\
&= \frac{1}{n \cdot n!},
\end{align*}
as expected.

Comment: I really like this approach (+1).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{i(i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+n)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{i(i+1)\cdots(i+n-1)}-\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)\cdots(i+n)}.\right)$$

The first term of this series becomes 
$$=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right) $$

The second term becomes 
$$=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{2}{(n+2)!}\right) $$

The third term becomes 
$$=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2}{(n+2)!}-\frac{6}{(n+3)!}\right)$$

Hence we see that the sum telescopes to $\frac {1}{n. n!}$

Comment: Isn't this exactly like Math Lover's answer? Perhaps you can include how you arrived at the final step...

Answer (score 1):

I will add another answer with a different approach (less elementary but also interesting). From [finite calculus theory](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) your series can also be stated as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^\overline n}=\frac1{1^\overline n}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^\overline n}=\frac1{n!}+\sum\nolimits_2^\infty (k-1)^\underline{-n}\delta k$$ where $a^\overline c$ is a rising factorial and $a^\underline c$ is a falling factorial. Hence

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^\overline n}&=\frac1{n!}+\frac{(k-1)^\underline{1-n}}{1-n}\bigg|_{k=2}^{k\to\infty}\\&=\frac1{n!}+0-\frac{1^\underline{1-n}}{1-n}\\&=\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n-1)2^\overline{n-1}}\\&=\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n-1)n!}\\
&=\frac1{n!\, n}\end{align}$$

because $\frac{a^\underline m}{m}$ is a primitive (in the finite calculus sense) of $a^\underline {m-1}$, in the domain where both expressions are well-defined.